# What is the meaning of the "." (dot) in R?

Tags: r

I'm just reading the book "R in a Nutshell".
And it seems as if I skipped the part where the "." as in "sample.formula" was explained.

```
> sample.formula <- as.formula(y~x1+x2)
```

Is sample an object with a field formula as in other languages? And if so, how can I find out, what other fields/functions this object has? (Type declaration)

EDIT:
I just found another confusing use of the ".":

```
> svm(formula = is_spam~., data = spambase.training)
```

(the dot between ~., )

Comment: The dot you see with the is_spam~. command means that there are no explanatory variables. Typically with model formulas, you will see y~x, but if you have no x variable, y~. says to guess at the value of y using no other variables. This is the same as the model $y=\beta_0$

Comment: @Christopher On the contrary, the `.` in the formula tells R to use all variables in the dataframe `spambase.training` (except `is_spam`) as predictors. The model $y = \beta_{0}$ is fit with `y ~ 1`.

Comment: I didn't check sources beforehand. Thank you for the correction!

Comment: @caracal (+1) Wow I was just wondering how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The dot can be used as in normal name. It has however additional special interpretation. Suppose we have an object with specific class:

```
 a <- list(b=1)
 class(a) <- "myclass"
```

Now declare `myfunction` as standard generic in the following way:

```
 myfunction <- function(x,...) UseMethod("myfunction")
```

Now declare the function

```
 myfunction.myclass <- function(x,...) x$b+1
```

Then the dot has special meaning. For all objects with class `myclass` calling

```
 myfunction(a)
```

will actualy call function `myfunction.myclass`:

```
 > myfunction(a)
  [1] 2
```

This is used widely in R, the most apropriate example is function `summary`. Each class has its own `summary` function, so when you fit some model for example (which usually returns object with specific class), you need to invoke `summary` and it will call appropriate summary function for that specific model.

Comment: I am very surprised this answer was accepted and upvoted so much, because it doesn't answer the question at all!  It refers to the *ellipsis* `...` (which is a single lexeme, not a sequence of three different ones) as a "dot" whereas the question clearly means a *dot* `.` as used in formulas and names in an entirely different way, as correctly described in a contemporaneous answer by Chase.

Comment: Well I do not refer to the ellipsis. I tried to explain that the dot is used for S3 method dispatch. The generic functions usually have ellipses, that is why I used them. If they are removed from the code, the answer would not change. I can only guess that I gave the answer before the edit, since I would give a different answer now after rereading the question body.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I think the appearance of "..." two times misled me into believing you were referring to it as a "dot".

Answer (score 12):

Look at the help page for `?formula` with regard to `.` Here's the relevant bits:

> There are two special interpretations of . in a formula. The usual one
>   is in the context of a data argument of model fitting functions and
>   means ‘all columns not otherwise in the formula’: see terms.formula.
>   In the context of update.formula,  only, it means ‘what was previously
>   in this part of the formula’.

Alternatively, the `reshape` and `reshape2` packages use `.` and `...` a bit differently (from `?cast`):

> There are a couple of special variables: "..." represents all other
>   variables not used in the formula and "." represents no variable

Answer (score 5):

There are some exceptions (S3 method dispatch), but generally it is simply used as legibility aid, and as such has no special meaning.

Comment: I would say the opposite - it has special meaning (the S3 dispatch you mention), but some old naming conventions caused function names that are not S3 generics to have names that include a `.`. That pertains to names of functions. As for names of (non-function) objects, then yes, there is no special meaning.

Comment: At the beginning of a name, a `.` makes the object invisible to `ls()` though.

Answer (score 2):

The dot in **sample.formula** doesn't separate **sample** from **formula**, other than visually. It is just a variable name. R variables names can consist of alphanumerics and dot (.) and underscore (_) with one exception. Here is the actual rule:

"*A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed by a number. Names such as ".2way" are not valid, and neither are the reserved words.*"

The second case (i.e., the case of **is_spam~.**) is different and is explained above.